# How do I create a histogram from a hashmap in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, hashmap, histogram

I have data in a hashmap, and I want to create a histogram over this data using the keys as bins and the values as data.

My data:

```
N = {1: 12, 2: 15, 3: 8, 4: 4, 5: 1}
```

What I want plotted:

```
  |
15|    X
  |    X 
  |    X
  | X  X
  | X  X
10| X  X
  | X  X
  | X  X  X
  | X  X  X
  | X  X  X
 5| X  X  X
  | X  X  X  X
  | X  X  X  X
  | X  X  X  X
  | X  X  X  X  X
  |_________________________
    1  2  3  4  5
```

I've tried to figure out how to do this with `pyplot.hist()`, but all overloads I can find take a list of values, not a hashmap. Do I really have to generate this list, just to let matplotlib count all the values *again*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just plot a bar graph. That's all `hist` does.

E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = {1: 12, 2: 15, 3: 8, 4: 4, 5: 1}
plt.bar(N.keys(), N.values(), align='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get a list:

```
my_list = N.values()
```

That structure is called a dictionary in Python BTW.